# Reduce idle timeout in Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, single-page-application, dyno

I have a React static Single Page Application deployed in Heroku.

The default idle timeout is 30 minutes as I can see in [Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping). But in my case, since its an SPA with a **single bundle** I want it to *go to sleep* much faster, since I will be wasting 30 minutes of free Dyno time to serve a single file in this current configuration.

How can I reduce the idle timeout to, for example, 1 minute?